# Norms on $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

On the space of all matrices $n \times n$ with real coefficients $\mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ we define two norms:

$||A||_1 := sup_{x\neq 0; x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||} \\
||A||_2 := max |A_{ij}|.$

It's quite evident that these are indeed norms, but I'm having trouble proving that there exists a $C_n>1$ s.t. $\frac{1}{C_n } \le \frac{||A||_1}{||A||_2} \le C_n$.

Could you help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|A\|_2\leq \|A\|_1\leq n\|A\|_2$
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me why that is, I mean - why does $n$ work here?

Comment: There are a lot of reference we can get b googling. For eample, http://www.ece.uah.edu/courses/ee448/chapter4.pdf. In fact, it is becasue every finite dimensional Banach spaces are isomorphic. In your question, it the Euclidean norm and the $\ell^\infty$ norm.